# ActiveMQ STOMP Client access

Tags: activemq-classic, stomp

We are planning to use ActiveMQ (STOMP) for one of our project. One of the requirement is to kick out/ban a user if we find them to be inappropriate.  How can this be achieved with STOMP? Something like a KICK in IRC.

Answer (score 3):

ActiveMQ's JMX interface allows you to stop a connection which would act like a kick.  For a ban, you would need to setup ActiveMQ to JAAS security.  Then it would just be a matter of disabling access to that user.